# Leave just overlapping dates in the list

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have a list of sessions expirations time and session timeout value.
So I can get session start time subtracting timeout from expiration time.

I know how to check if two dates is overlapping:

```
public boolean isOverlapped(LocalDateTime start1, LocalDateTime end1,
                            LocalDateTime start2, LocalDateTime end2) {
    return (start1.isBefore(end2) || start1.equals(end2)) 
            && (start2.isBefore(end1) || start2.equals(end2));
}
```

but have no idea how to do this with for list of dates.

In result I want to have list with the longest chain of  overlapped(concurrent) sessions.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: "Overlapping" is a four-place relation between dates. So if each list element is one date, what does it mean to have a list with "only dates which is [sic] overlapping"?

Comment: You need to devise a set of test data that encompasses all the possible meanings of "overlap" that you are interested in and show the input and expected output.  I'm not sure you are clear on what you want the results to be yet.  One possible unambiguous definition would be to identify spans of time that are members of more than one interval, and then output all intervals that contain one of those spans of time.  However, that might not be what YOU mean by "overlapping".  As it stands right now, this question might get closed as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: How is your list holding the start dates and end dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make a new class that represents these sessions (if you don't have one already):

```
class Session {
    private LocalDateTime start;
    private LocalDateTime end;  

    public boolean isOverlapped(Session other) {
        return (start.isBefore(other.end) || start.equals(other.end)) 
            && (end.isAfter(other.start) || end.equals(other.start));
    }
    ...     
}
```

Your input list will have to be a list of `Session`s.

Next, here is an algorithm that does what you asked for; It takes in a list and checks for each element if it overlaps with *any* other element in the list (except for itself). If that is the case, it puts it in the result list:

```
public static List<Session> filter(List<Session> in) {
    List<Session> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Session current : in) {
        for(Session other : in) {
            if(current != other && current.isOverlapped(other)) {
                result.add(current);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is also an example program: [<kbd>Ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/mBoUDv)

The result will be a list containing sessions that were concurrent with any other session.

Comment: Thanks for help! Maybe description of problem is not clear enough. Using suggested algorithm we get list of sessions overlapped with any other session. But what if I want to get the longest chain of concurrent sessions. Any ideas?

Comment: @user936 That is a step up in complexity. I might look into it later.

Comment: I don't know is it right but I create map which has session as key and list of overlapped sessions with it as a value. I use your filter method with little changes (In result I add other session). So in this way I have map and than just sort this map by values list size and get first element from map.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather classic problem. You didn't specify if you want the longest session in terms of time or in terms of number of intervals, but they both work the same way.

First sort all your sessions by start time. Then the logic would be the following:

```
current_chain = []
best_chain = []
for session in sessions_sorted_by_start:
    if session doesn't overlap with any session in curent_chain:  [1]
        update best_chain if current_chain is better              [2]
        current_chain = []
    current_chain.insert(session)                                 [3]
update best_chain if current_chain is better                      [2]
```

The idea here is the following: we maintain a current chain. If a new session overlaps with any other session in the chain, we just add it to the chain. If it doesn't overlap with any session in the current chain, then its start is to the right from the end of the furthest session in the current chain, so no other remaining session will overlap with anything in the current chain (since they are sorted by the start date). That means that the current chain is as long as it will ever get, so we can check if it is better than the best chain so far ([2]) based on whichever criteria (time or number of sessions), and reset it.

Now, to make it linear in time it would be cool to do overlap check of a session and a chain at [1] in constant time. This is easily done if for the chain you always maintain the furthest session in it. To do it, when you insert a new session at [3], if its end extends beyond the end of the current furthest session, update the furthest session, otherwise do not. This way at [1] you only need to check the overlap with the furthest session, instead of checking all of them, which makes that particular check constant time, and the entire algorithm linear (if you do not account for initial sorting, which is of course `O(n log n)`).